# can't seem to get this array to work with splice

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am trying to get a new fortune to get included into my array when someone submits a fortune but I can't get it to work now matter what im trying. Do I like it to the other file where someones submit their fortune, or am I messing up somewhere else?

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
import AddFortune from "./add-fortune";

class Fortune extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        fortunes: [
            "An exciting opporunity lies ahead",
            "A long time friend will brirng wise advice in the coming week",
            "You will find great fortunes in unexpected places",
            "Never give up... Unless you want to thats cool too",
            "111",
            "222",
            "333",
            "444",
            "Maybe a nap is what you need",
            "Don't Text Your EX!"
        ],
        array.push('
        fortune: "" ');
        array.splice(array.length, 0, '{fortune:""}');
        array[array.length] = fortune: "";
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getFortune();
}

getFortune = () =>  {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.state.fortunes.length) + 0)
    console.log(rand);
    this.setState({
        fortune: this.state.fortunes[rand]
    })
}



render() {
    return (
        <body>
        <div className="home-buttons-wrapper">
            
            <button onClick={this.getFortune}>Your Fortune</button>
            
            
        </div>
        <h5>{this.state.fortune}</h5>
        </body>
    )
}
}

console.log('getFortune');

export default Fortune;
```

What im trying to get to be added to the fortunes file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class AddFortune extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            nameInput: "",
            loading: false,
            error: false
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        this.setState({
            loading: true,
            error: false
        })

        fetch("https://backend-edwin.herokuapp.com/item/add", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: this.state.nameInput
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.id) {
                this.props.history.push("/fortune")
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("Error adding fortune ", error)

            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                error: true
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='add-item-wrapper'>
                <h2>Add Fortune</h2>

                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="fortune"
                        name="nameInput" 
                        value={this.state.nameInput}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />

    
                    <button type="submit" disabled={this.state.loading}>Add Fortune</button>
                </form>

                {this.state.loading ? <div className="loading">Submitting...</div> : null}

                {this.state.error ? <div className="error">An error occured... Please try again later.</div> : null}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: didnt understand the purpose of  `        array.push('
        fortune: "" ');
        array.splice(array.length, 0, '{fortune:""}');
        array[array.length] = fortune: "";
    }`. this code? what you are trying to do with this?

Comment: I think I got confused with it. Im trying to add on to the fortunes @sojin

Comment: Are you trying to replace first item in fortunes array ?

Comment: im trying to include it on the list that I currently have. @sojin

Comment: Will update a solution in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method to get a random fortune from a list of fortunes.

```
import React from "react";

class Fortune extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        fortunes: [],
        fortune: '',
        loading: true,
        error: false
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://backend-edwin.herokuapp.com/item/", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        fortunes: data, //check how the data is coming from api and add the variable here if  fortunes list `if data.fortunes` then add data.fortunes here 
        error: false
      }, this.getFortune)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error fetching fortune ", error)
        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            error: true
        })
    })
  }

getFortune = () =>  {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.state.fortunes.length - 1) + 0)
    console.log(rand);
    this.setState({
        fortune: this.state.fortunes[rand]
    })
}



render() {
   if(this.state.loading) {
     return (<div>Loading .....</div>)
   }
   if(this.state.error) {
    return (<div>Error occurred in API</div>)
  }
    return (
        <div>
        <div className="home-buttons-wrapper">
            
            <button onClick={this.getFortune}>Your Fortune</button>
            
            
        </div>
        <h5>{this.state.fortune}</h5>
        </div>
    )
}
}
export default Fortune
```

Comment: So would that then mean that when I submit a new fortune it would get added on to the list? Im sorry if it sounds like a dumb question im still learning and his part confuses me

Comment: Show me the code where you are trying to submit a new fortune

Comment: I want to add it on to fortunes part. I made a separate file that has the submitting part.

Comment: add that to your question

Comment: I added the file that I have for submitting fortunes

Comment: newly added fortune is storing data to a server DB using an API, it will not update content in another listing screen, also in the listing screen, you are just showing thehardcoded list of fortunes. You need to integrate API here and fetch the fortunes from API first and after that when you switch to the listing page it will automatically fetch all your latest data from the API including the newly created one

Comment: could you point in what I would have to look up to learn how to do this?

Comment: Bro, integration of API is already implemented in your add fortune file. similarly, you need to fetch items from the server in your listing screen, I will update my answer with an example

Comment: Updated with a sample API call, you need to check the correct API URL and the data received from that API, as you know we cant check your API and results from here